# What are the attributes for identifying elements in watir-webdriver?

Tags: automated-tests, watir-webdriver

In Watir we have a grid of all elements and how they can be discovered ([here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir)). In Watir-Webdriver we do not. Is there a grid online, or a way to discover what attributes can be used on what elements?

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty much the same as the Watir ones, when converting my test scripts from Watir to web driver I didn't find any that were not supported.

The class list on the API Docs http://jarib.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/# will show you all the elements supported.

Comment: I can add that any HTML attributes appear to be supported, :html is not supported, neither is :after?, so they definitely are different. At the moment I'm presuming that only the attributes of the html are supported, plus index.

Comment: Not had call to use those yet. Luckily most of our elements have IDs.

Comment: There is a well used Google group for webdriver, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/webdriver if you've not tried there to find an answer.

Comment: Yeah ZK-generated elements have IDs but they're never so boring to be the same on each page load :). Thanks for the link, I'll take a look today.